# Uiimageview not moving

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have 4 image views on a view.I want to make the 4 images movable.I used touches moved method.It seems to work for 3 of my image views .However the fourth one is not moving.The touch is detected in all cases which i have verified by NSlog.Please help.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touch view] == textstyleImage) {
        textstyleImage.center = location; 
        }
    else if ([touch view] == clipartImage){
        clipartImage.center = location;

    }
    else if([touch view] == customMessage){
        customMessage.center = location;
    }
    else if([touch view] == galleryImage){
        galleryImage.center = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show some code to heal your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable user interaction for that imageview like this

```
[fourthImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

and test it again.

Comment: I have set this in my viewdidload.however it still doesnt work.

Comment: did you add it as a subview to the view? Please check sometimes we will forget to add.

Comment: Yes.I have added it.The subview is displayed on my view as required.Even my touch is detected.

Comment: okay then set tag values to each imageview and check the condition like this: if ([touch view].tag == 0) { }

Comment: That is not working.Now none of the images are moving.The value of the tag always is the same.

Comment: -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touch view].tag == 0) {
        textstyleImageView.center = location; 
    }
    else if ([touch view].tag == 1){
        clipartImageView.center = location;
    }
    else if([touch view].tag == 2){
        message.center = location;

    }
    else if([touch view].tag == 3){
        galleryImage.center = location;
    }
}

Comment: give me your email id. I have created a sample. It is working for me.

Comment: Checked your code.I have done almost similar way except that i add the images to imageviews through my code and not directly in ib.But the issue still persists.

Comment: Solved the issue.The problem was that i had used a frame for that particular imageview.when i removed the frame it worked.